# Navigo JS Router - Duplicate routing issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application, router, es6-modules

Not sure what the issue is but my [Navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) router is duplicating routes.

**The Router:**

```
this.Navigo.hooks({
    before: (done, params) => {
        // some tomfoolery
        done();
    }
});

this.Navigo.on({
    '/:region/travel': (params) => {
        // import Travel module
        // some nonsense
    },
    '/:region/travel/car': (params) => {
        // import TravelCar module
        // some nonsense
    }
)};

this.Navigo.resolve();
```

**The Problem**

```
this.Navigo.navigate('/london/travel/car');
```

Navigating to `/london/travel/car` is also triggering the route for `/london/travel` and thus causing all kinds of twaddle.

Is this standard behaviour? If not, what could be wrong?

I could rewrite the routes so they don't collide e.g. `/london/travel-by-car`, but I really don't want to if I can avoid it.

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried switching the order of routes but makes no difference. I did this by declaring the longest `travel` routes first, `/:region/travel/car`, and the smallest, `/:region/travel`, last.

**UPDATE 2:**

The more I look into this, the more I'm convinced this cannot be achieved with Navigo. Navigo do not support nested routes. If somebody could confirm that my routes are in fact 'nested', I will use an alternative routing library that does support them.

Answer (score 0):

My code is a little different, but works the way you expect:

```
    var router = new Navigo("/");
var render = (content) => (document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = content);

router
.on('/:id', ({ data }) => {
        setuserId(data.id)
        if (verifiedUser) {
            console.log("User verified");
        } else {
            console.log("User NOT verified");
        }
        rendertemplate(userDataURL(), "#landing-template", "#app")
    })
    .on('/:id/q', ({ data }) => {
        // Example - flaging a send with 's' from 'SMS', perhaps a diff flow?
        setuserId(data.id)
        rendertemplate(userDataURL(), "#landing-template", "#app")
        console.log("Source was a QRcode");
    })
    .on('/:id/q/t', ({ data }) => {
        // Example - flaging a send with 's' from 'SMS', perhaps a diff flow?
        setuserId(data.id)
        rendertemplate(userDataURL(), "#landing-template", "#app")
        console.log("Source was a QRcode in a Train");
    })
```

This will give me a single discreet ".. verified"/"Source was a QRcode"/"Source was a QRcode in a Train" console.log response.

B